# Why would Eclipse C ndk jni execution speed be 6 times slower than gcc shell?

Tags: android-ndk

I have a program which uses C ndk subroutines in jni which processes a 3204x2406 image file which takes 6+ seconds when run *(without debug) by eclipse with NDK_DEBUG=0.

I've got the same code compiled with GCC on the android running in the shell at under 1 second.

The code consists of loops and integer math. Both the eclipse ndk program and the gcc shell program access the exact same file from the exact same location. There are no trace statements within the 6 seconds. The only external calls is 2406 read statements.

The eclipse is the google integrated download 21.0.0, which is uses Juno 4.2.1 and c/c++ 8.1.1. And yes, i've restarted eclipse and cleaned the project.

I'm now thinking about trying to call or link to the GCC code, but keep feeling like I must be missing something silly.

Comment: What is "GCC shell on Android ?" I'm assuming Java and Android OS activity cycle code is eating performance big-time. Java has no temporary variables so it could make dozens of allocations if it passes through java code.

Comment: "GCC shell on the android" is a native gcc compiler on the android, where c/c++ programs are compiled and run though the linux shell of the android, without any java, NDK or eclipse. The NDK C code is called with a single function from java, so there should be no java involved.